# Understanding Oren-Nayar reflectance model

Tags: graphics, 3d, specular

> In the Oren–Nayar reflectance model, each facet is assumed to be Lambertian in reflectance. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oren%E2%80%93Nayar_reflectance_model)

My understanding :

Law of reflection tells us that angle of incidence is equal to angle of reflection. So on a perfectly smooth surface, we get specular reflection. On a rough surface, an incident beam is scattered in a number of directions (each ray obeying law of reflection). To model this, a microfacet model is used which defines grooves (facets) on the surface. Now what does a lambertian facet mean? Are we assuming grooves on the already present grooves?

Answer (score 1):

**Lambertian BRDF** is a theoretical model describing perfect diffuse reflection.

**Microfacet BRDFs** on the other hand are based on geometrical optics theory, where a surface is covered with microfacets and described by means of statistical distributions.

**Oren-Nayar BRDF** is an improvement over the theoretical Lambertian model, applying  distribution of purely diffuse microfacets. So to answer your question - **Lambertian microfacet is an entity itself not subject to microfacet theory, it's not a "groove with grooves". It's a purely theoretical concept used to apply microfacet theory to matte surfaces.** There are many different BRDF models, only some of them follow geometrical optics like the microfacet models do, it is useful to keep in mind that microfacet is not a universal theory.

For further reading, I recommend the overview of BRDF models by Montes and Ureña, their classification was very enlightening to me at least.